# What can trigger a form submit on disabled JavaScript without button-/input (of type submit)-tags

Tags: javascript

I have a form which should never be submitted on disabled JavaScript.

```
<form id="xxx" name="xxx" action="xxx">
  <input type="hidden" name="age">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

It has no button-tags or an input-tag with type "submit" (`<input type="submit"`). Could any other action (besides enabled JavaScript and client-side manipulation) submit this form?

Comment: I cannot imagine any other way besides manually posting to the action URL (but those capable of going that path won't probably have JS disabled).

Comment: maybe you could add a hidden field with javascript on page load with some sort of token, and then check in your backend if this token is set. if it isn't you know the form was posted with js disabled

Comment: Its more of a "feasibility"-question. Not about, what to do if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Browser can fire submit event with [key shortcuts](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10451/keyboard-shortcut-for-submit-form), but it depends on browser and I can't see any other possibilities.

Comment: I know I can submit this form when I have "<input type="submit" ..." with a keyboard-shortcut (most time default is the Enter-key). Without this input I could not submit it.